# Django-Userena: adding extra non-null fields to a user's profile

Tags: python, django

Is there an easy way to allow for required profile fields?

I am using userena in my current django project. I have a custom profile called UserProfile which has a start_year none-blank, non-null field as defined below.

```
class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile, PybbProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True,
                        verbose_name=_('user'),
                        related_name='user_profile')

    start_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
```

I need this to be filled-in on signup. I created a SignupExtraForm as defined below, to override the default form.

```
class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    start_year = forms.IntegerField(label=_(u'Initiation Year'),
                            min_value=1800,
                            max_value=datetime.now().year,
                            required=True)

    def save(self):
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()

        new_user_profile = new_user.get_profile()

        new_user_profile.start_year = self.cleaned_data['start_year']
        new_user_profile.save()

        # Userena expects to get the new user from this form, so return the new
        # user.
        return new_user
```

When I attempt to add a new user thru the now modified form I get the below error:

```
profile_userprofile.start_year may not be NULL
```

With the stack trace pointing at `new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save())`, in the code above.

I think this has to do with the user profile being created and saved before I am able to give it the required data from the form. Is there an easy way of supplying this data to the user_creation process, or delaying the creating of the user profile?

Thanks
Shon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserProfile` is created after the `User` is saved by a `post_save` signal. Even if you override it with your own signal, you won't have access to the form data from there.

The easiest solution is to just allow `start_year` to be NULL. It's not necessary to enforce this at the database level, and you can make the field required in all forms either way:

```
start_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=True)
```

Your custom form already enforces that the field is required, so you're done.

**UPDATE (from comment)**

Custom form, yes, but you can still use a `ModelForm`:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_year'].required = True
```

**UPDATE (again)**

Actually, I didn't think before my last update. I put `blank=False` on the `start_year` field in my example. That will force that the field is required in all `ModelForm`s by default. You don't need a custom `ModelForm` at all. However, I left the previous update for posterity.

Comment: Userena doesn't use the post_save signal.The `UserProfile` is actually created in the when `UserenaManager.create_user()`, is called in the `SignupForm.save()`.

Comment: Your are correct and I have thought of this, but it just seems dirty to me. I am hoping that I missed some setting or something else...

Comment: Sorry thought of a problem with this. When setting up editing for the profile i will be forced to use custom form instead of a ModelForm, because the field will not force validation.

Comment: See my updates above. I gave you a sample `ModelForm` you can use if you really need it, but the `blank=False` argument makes the field required for the purposes of forms, so it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the how blank vs null worked with regards to ModelForms.